# Why i3lock and xautolock and not xscreensaver?

Tags: i3, xscreensaver

I'm just trying understand why `i3` created their own utilities,

- `i3lock`
- `xautolock`

It seems this is just something `xscreensaver` should be doing? What's the advantage of *not* using xscreensaver? Did `i3` get any cool functionality by not going with `xscreensaver`?

Comment: i'd really go and ask the i3 developers, they know best. and i3 has a reputation of being an user friendly project when it comes down to fair technical questions like this one

Comment: Did you find out why?

Comment: @SILENT nope, seems like a case of not-invented-here to me